# Code declared in .h and defined in .cpp gives error when calling dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using C# COM in unmanaged C++ project -> First-chance exception at 0x7697C41F (KernelBase.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724006/using-c-sharp-com-in-unmanaged-c-project-first-chance-exception-at-0x7697c4)

I have a project that was upgraded from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010 (Project1) and outputs a dll.  It is c++ with clr (it interfaces with a c# project).

I am using the dll from another VS2010 project(Project 2) (both have the same c++ target, both debug and both Win 32).

In project2, the dll interface makes use of a class that is used statically.
Here's where the problem occurs.  As of now, if I execute functions declared in the .h, but defined in the cpp, I get an error.  If the function is declared and defined in the .h, then there are no problems.
[image: Error from trying to access function defined in cpp]

This worked prior to the upgrade to VS 2010.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If the function is defined in the .h then it's no longer part of the DLL, or rather it may exist both in the application *and* the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the functions that **should** be in the DLL are correctly exported (meaning "stored" in the binary) with __declspec(dllexport).

Comment: Well, the externally visble functions are ok it seems (I can step into them and debug them), but the problem occurs when the function tries to call a function declared in a static class (but defined in that class' cpp)

Answer (score 0):

From the link provided by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) about a similar error code, it seems that this error is an undocumented exception that occurs from the IPC protocol used in debug mode on startup of .Net 4.0 clr and is safe to ignore.

[Link to answer on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/clr/thread/bca092d4-d2b5-49ef-8bbc-cbce2c67aa89)