# First-chance exception at...(KERNELBASE.DLL) in TaskHost.exe when calling a 3rd-party library

Tags: dll, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, first-chance-exception

I want to use libsamplerate library in my windows phone project.So I add its lib file to the linker input.As I run the project it doesn't even reach the native code entry point that I set a breakpoint there and encounter the error:

> First-chance exception at 0x7723277C (KERNELBASE.DLL) in TaskHost.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x8007007E, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x70BF0000).

As I comment the method which belong to libsamplerate library the error doesn't appear anymore. I searched the web for days with no successful result.

I had tried to use other 3d party library in windows phone runtime component and always encounter the same error.

What circumstances should the library have to be used in windows phone runtime component?
Can we use typical libraries in it or not?

Comment: It's really strange.Isn't there anybody that use a 3rd party library in a wrc which can answer my question??:(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724006/using-c-sharp-com-in-unmanaged-c-project-first-chance-exception-at-0x7697c4

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem today with my "Direct3D with XAML" Windows Phone app. Although  the address of the exception was different it turned out that one of the 3rd party libs wasn't  on the phone. When I added the extra reference all worked fine for me.

Comment: Finding the 3rd party dll's source files and make a windows phone runtime dll was the solution I found for my problem.