# Can std::cout be redirected to output view in Visual Studio 2010 C++ out-of-the-box?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to know if this can be done in the latest version of VS by a simple setting somewhere that causes VS to behave in a way that is equivalent to "ContextMenu">run "a_Java_src_file_with_main" in the Eclipse IDE. I'm using the trial version of VS 2010 Pro on a new W7 platform. Even the minimal helloworld cpp source file added to a project generated from the "empty" template redirects into a command window.

Same question 3 years ago:
[Capturing cout in Visual Studio 2005 output window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286/capturing-cout-in-visual-studio-2005-output-window)

And 9 months ago:
[How to redirect stdout to output window from visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248704/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-output-window-from-visual-studio)

I'm aware of using OutputDebugString(...) and of redirecting the stream to a file as alternatives.
[Capture console output for debugging in VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122778/capture-console-output-for-debugging-in-vs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect stdout to output window from visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248704/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-output-window-from-visual-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect Console.Write... Methods to Visual Studio's Output Window While Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518509/redirect-console-write-methods-to-visual-studios-output-window-while-debuggi)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this is to "[suppress the console window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319547/6547185)" by building an executable with a [`WinMain` entry point on windows instead of `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518683/6547185).

This can usually be done by editing the project settings, but if you use `cmake`, like me, these settings are overwritten every time you call the `cmake` build. So, in this case you need to [add `WIN32` to executable target in `CMakeList.txt` or set `CMAKE_WIN32_EXECUTABLE` to true for `cmake` configure command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886628/6547185).